# Fast way to get vector of smallest distances in openCV feature matching

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I am using the python version of openCV to develop a "similarity score" for two images.
First I find the keypoints and their descriptors for each image (e.g. using ORB or AKAZE).
Then I match these keypoints across the to images and save these matches in a list `matches`.
For every match `x` in `matches` I can get the distance between the corresponding key points via `x.distance`.

My similarity score should now be the sum of the `k` smallest distances found in the matching algorithm. Obviously, I could get this score as (assuming `k < len(matches)`):

```
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
score = 0
for l in range(k):
    score += matches[l].distance
```

However, this loop is very slow. Is there a vectorised version of `.distance` that I could use to transform `matches` directly into a list of floats?

Clearly, there are also other ways of doing this. But they are all quite slow (as in, they mean that I loop over the matches in some way).

Thank you!

Comment: what is the idea behind summing up the k smallest distances? Search for k-nearest-neighbor search, there you"ll get directly what you need. OpenCV's DescriptorMatcher provides matcher->knnMatch. In tutorials they typically choose k = 2 but should probably work with arbitrary k, too. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d6f/tutorial_feature_flann_matcher.html

Comment: @Micka: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I need to clarify this a bit. Given images 1 and 2 my goal is to get a score of how similar these to images are. If the smallest k distances between matched features is small, these images will be very similar. 

In contrast to that, knnMatch would give me the k keypoints in Image 2 that are most similar to a given keypoint in Image 1.

Comment: ok, you only want to analyze k different keypoints, not the k best matches of each keypoint. Are you sure the loop is slow? How big is your k? How many matches do you have in total? Sorting with a quicksort should be fast. Loop shouldn't be that slow.